# a.exe has stopped working

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
char *createP(int);
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char str[100];
    printf("int n = ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("string str = ");
    scanf("%s",&str);
    if(n>40)
            return -1;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
        if(str[i]=='X' || str[i]=='Y' || str[i]=='Z')
            continue;
            else
             return -1;
    char *P;
    P=createP(n);
    printf("The generated string is = %s",P);
    return 0;
}
char *createP(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
            return "X";
    if(n==1)
        return "Y";
    if(n==2)
        return "Z";
    if(n>2)
        return strcat(createP(n-2),createP(n-3));
}
```

I am trying to create a string for the following question :

P(0) = 'X'

P(1) = 'Y'

P(2) = 'Z'

P(n) = P(n-2) + P(n-3), n>2
where + denotes string concatenation.
I am using recursion (which looks quite obvious) for this problem.But my .exe is not working.

Comment: that should have been an "error" during compilation, but the code is getting compiled. The .exe is crashing since the error is during runtime .

Comment: What parameters are you passing for this program ?

Comment: n=6 and str = "XY" ....str can be ignored in this case

Comment: Please put more effort into it when asking a question, here. This concerns the contents of your question (where is your question?) as well has the writing in itself. Your question title is just worth nothing. What information do you think that your title provides?

Comment: @JensGustedt ....I apologize if my question was unclear. Posted in lot of hurry. Will definitely try to put more thoughts on the title from my next question ...  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a dynamic list, using only `char *P` don't let you use it as string at all.

Try to declare `char P[100]` , and at the end of the recursion put `\0` char.

EDIT:

something like that:

```
void createP(int n,int index)
{
    if(n==0)
            P[index] = "X";
            return ;

    if(n>2)
        return strcat(createP(n-2,index + 2),createP(n-3,index + 3));
}
```

While P is global string, and index start with 0.

Comment: Okay, but how do I concat two charecters in the final step of recursion

Answer (score 2):

You are using strcat wrongly.

> char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
>
> Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The terminating null character >in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a null-character is >included at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

Try using something like this instead,

```
char *createP(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
            return "X";
    if(n==1)
            return "Y";
    if(n==2)
            return "Z";
    if(n>2)
    {   
    
            char *P = calloc (n, sizeof(char));
            strcat(P, createP(n-2));
            strcat(P, createP(n-3));
            return P;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Memory was not allocated correctly, I had the same problem when I declared

```
type array[20];
```

and than called `array[20]=...;`

The solution was that it was needed to declare `type array[21];`)